# What is the correct form for a webpage in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

What is the correct format for the *biblatex* entry for a webpage? The *biblatex* documentation mentions only `@online`, but my tools generate `@webpage`. Is there a difference between these, or are they equivalent?

For example, is the following correct?

```
@webpage{MathGroupsQ,
organization={Mathematics - Stack Exchange},
title = {{Is the “binary operation” in the definition of a group always deterministic?}},
year = {2012},
url = {http://math.stackexchange.com/q/148970/}
}
```

Comment: The entry types `@electronic` and `@www` are aliases for `@online`. The term `@webpage` is definitely outside biblatex's standard terminology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`webpage` is not a standard biblatex entry type. However, this is not really a problem if you have no way to make it output something different. With biblatex 2.0+biber 1.0, you could put this in your preamble:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[typesource=webpage, typetarget=online]
    }
  }
}
```

Or equivalently, this in your biber.conf to set this as a type alias you always want to use :

```
<sourcemap>
  <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
    <map>
      <map_step map_type_source="WEBPAGE" map_type_target ="ONLINE"/>
    </map>
  </maps>
</sourcemap>
```

Additionally, biblatex and biber will, in the not too distant future, support a configurable data model so you will be able to make `webpage` a genuine entry type for biblatex.